# how can I flatten an 2d numpy array, which has different length in the second axis?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array which looks like:

```
myArray = np.array([[1,2],[3]])
```

But I can not flatten it,

```
In: myArray.flatten()
Out: array([[1, 2], [3]], dtype=object)
```

If I change the array to the same length in the second axis, then I can flatten it.

```
In: myArray2 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
In: myArray2.flatten()
Out: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

My Question is:

Can I use some thing like `myArray.flatten()` regardless the dimension of the array and the length of its elements, and get the output: `array([1,2,3])`?

Comment: NumPy does not support ragged arrays and there is little point in using NumPy for arrays of objects (in this case lists) as you have in this question. e.g. `2 * myArray` will give you `array([[1, 2, 1, 2], [3, 3]], dtype=object)`. You might want to rethink your problem or post a question about what is happening at an earlier stage of your code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`myArray` is a 1-dimensional array of *objects*. Your list objects will simply remain in the same order with `flatten()` or `ravel()`. You can use [`hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) to stack the arrays in sequence horizontally:

```
>>> np.hstack(myArray)
array([1, 2, 3])
```

Note that this is basically equivalent to using [`concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) with an axis of 1 (*this should make sense intuitively*):

```
>>> np.concatenate(myArray, axis=1)
array([1, 2, 3])
```

If you *don't* have this issue however and *can* merge the items, it is always preferable to use `flatten()` or `ravel()` for performance:

```
In [1]: u = timeit.Timer('np.hstack(np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]))'\
   ....: , setup = 'import numpy as np')
In [2]: print u.timeit()
11.0124390125

In [3]: u = timeit.Timer('np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]).flatten()'\
   ....: , setup = 'import numpy as np')
In [4]: print u.timeit()
3.05757689476
```

[Iluengo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29518186/4686625) also has you covered for further information as to why you cannot use `flatten()` or `ravel()` given your array type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer very much! Does that means, what flatten() or ravel() can do, can also hstack() and concatenate(), which are more general?

Comment: I would use np.array(...).flatten()

Answer (score 9):

Well, I agree with the other answers when they say that `hstack` or `concatenate` do the job in this case. However, I would like to point that even if it 'fixes' the problem, the problem is not addressed properly.

The problem is that even if it looks like the second axis has different length, this is not true in practice. If you try:

```
>>> myArray.shape
(2,)
>>> myArray.dtype
dtype('O')    # stands for Object
>>> myArray[0]
[1, 2]
```

It shows you that your array is not a 2D array with variable size (as you might think), it is just a 1D array of objects. In your case, the elements are `list`, being the first element of your array a 2-element list and the second element of the array is a 1-element list.

So, `flatten` and `ravel` won't work because transforming 1D array to a 1D array results in exactly the same 1D array. If you have a `object` numpy array, it won't care about what you put inside, it will treat individual items as unkown items and can't decide how to merge them.

What you should have in consideration, is if this is the behaviour you want for your application. Numpy arrays are specially efficient with fixed-size numeric matrices. If you are playing with arrays of objects, I don't see why would you like to use Numpy instead of regular python lists.

Comment: I am new in python, the Numpy supplies many useful functions, so I don't need to write long codes just for small calcualtions like +,-, sum... :-)

Comment: @xirururu but, what I was trying to point, is that your array is not 2D. If you try `myArray + myArray` the result is `array([[1, 2, 1, 2], [3, 3]], dtype=object)` which I'm pretty sure is not what you expected. In order to use `+`, `-` and `sum` you need to make your array numeric, and to do so, it should be fixed size.

Comment: Thanks @iluengo. I really never expected this problem... :(

Comment: This is one way to look at the problem. However, from the user's perspective, being able to use flatten and mean is a *request for change* on numpy. It is important to keep this perspective in mind.

Answer (score 3):

`np.hstack` works in this case

```
In [69]: np.hstack(myArray)
Out[69]: array([1, 2, 3])
```