# numpy append to list then convert list to numpy

Tags: python, numpy

`class_i` is an *m* x *n* numpy array:

```
list = []
class_list=[class1,class2,class3,class4,class5,class6,class7]
for class_i in class_list:
   #data processing here
   list_1.append(class_i)

list_1 = np.array(list)
```

The `list_1` numpy array contains the classes as in the form:

```
[[ 314.5513238  314.4571136  314.2739476 ...      314.6        314.6        314.6      ]
 [ 314.5890785  314.5254568  314.4539721 ...      314.6        314.6        314.6      ]
 [ 314.5886471  314.4992394  314.3350225 ...      314.6        314.6        314.6      ]
 ...
```

which is wrong, it does not contain every single value of the numpy classes.

Any way to fix this?

Comment: I would avoid using `list` as a variable name to prevent shadowing the built-in list function. And to achieve what you want why not just `a = np.array(class_list)`

Comment: this is just an example, there is more processing of data in the for loop

Comment: What's the `shape` of `list_1`?  I don't think there's an issue with the `append`.  What do you get with `np.array(class_list)`?  And regarding the `...` - that's just a display feature.

Comment: class_i has shape (52L, 350L) and list_1 has shape (7L,) (wrong)

Comment: This is the shape of the elements being appended to the list in the for loop: (52L, 350L)
(26L, 700L)
(22L, 700L)
(15L, 700L)
(25L, 700L)
(21L, 700L)
(27L, 700L)
(26L, 700L)

Comment: What shape do you want the output array `list_1` to have? The row and column dimensions of the arrays in `list` do not all match.

Comment: I have found that the classes are being appended as **objects** to the list, so when converting the list to numpy array it does not contain all the values of the numpy arrays. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: The reason why they are objects is because numpy does not support ragged arrays. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/29626576/1461210 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/29518186/1461210.

Comment: what if they have same row size but different column size? is that possible?

Comment: @user3025898 No, numpy arrays have to have consistent sizes across each dimension. There are various workarounds you could use depending on what you want to do with the output. For example, you might fill in missing values with zeros or NaNs in order to make the dimensions of all your sub-arrays consistent.

Comment: OK, thank you this explains the results I am obtaining

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because what you are asking for (i.e. to create a ragged array whose dtype is not object) is simply not possible in numpy.