# Puzzled by odd NumPy error when creating array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

With

```
foo_ok = [(30, 784), (10, 30)]
foo_bad = [(10, 784), (10, 10)]
```

why does

```
np.array([np.zeros(foo_ok[0]),np.zeros(foo_ok[1])])
```

work while

```
np.array([np.zeros(foo_bad[0]),np.zeros(foo_bad[1])])
```

results in

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10,784) into shape (10)

Basically I need things that work with the form `foo = [(X, Z), (Y, X)]` where it might be the case that `Y==X`; but having `Y==X` causes things to fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited the answer according to the edited question.

Basically, the problem relies when the first axis matches on the 2 arrays. Find bellow a replicable example:

```
foo_ok = [(30, 784), (10, 30)]
foo_ok2 = [(30, 784), (30, 784)]
foo_bad = [(10, 784), (10, 10)]
```

If we construct the first 2 arrays:

```
a = np.array([np.zeros(foo_ok[0]),np.zeros(foo_ok[1])])
b = np.array([np.zeros(foo_ok2[0]),np.zeros(foo_ok2[1])])

c = np.array([np.zeros(foo_bad[0]),np.zeros(foo_bad[1])]) # ERROR
```

we can see that the resulting arrays are not the same:

```
>>> print a.shape, a.dtype, a[0].shape, a[1].shape
(2,), dtype('O'), (30, 784), (10, 30)

>>> print b.shape, b.dtype, b[0].shape, b[1].shape
(2, 30, 784), dtype('float64'), (30, 784), (30, 784)
```

Here `foo_ok2[0]` and `foo_ok2[1]` have the same values, thus, it will create 2 arrays of the same shape. Numpy is *smart* enough to handle array concatenations when 2 arrays with the same dimensions come, and the resulting `b` array is a concatenation of shape `(2, 30, 784)`. However, the resulting array `a` is just an array of type `object` with 2 elements. Each of the elements of the list is a different array (like if it was a raw python list).

Numpy is not optimized to deal with `object` arrays, and thus, whenever possible it tries to cast arrays to numerical data types.

That is what is happening then the first dimension of the 2 arrays matches in `c`. Numpy expects all the dimensions to match, and thus, throws a `I cannot concatenate this` exception.

---

Although I would still encourage not using numpy arrays with object types, there is a *dirty* way you can create one even when the first axis matches while the arrays have different shapes:

```
>>> c = np.array([np.zeros(foo_bad[0]), None])
>>> c[1] = np.zeros(foo_bad[1])

>>> print c.shape, c.dtype, c[0].shape, c[1].shape
(2,), dtype('O'), (10, 784), (10, 10)
```

And another version of it (closely related to your syntax):

```
>>> c = np.empty((2,), dtype=np.object)
>>> c[:] = [np.zeros(foo_bad[0]), np.zeros(foo_bad[1])]

>>> print c.shape, c.dtype, c[0].shape, c[1].shape
(2,), dtype('O'), (10, 784), (10, 10)
```

Comment: Hold on a sec. My error may lie elsewhere. Let me review before you invest more in this.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius just edited something quick that might help. Maybe `zeros` -> `zeros_like`?

Comment: Edited to simplify and make the question clearer. `zeros_like` doesn't do the trick. I'm looking for the the equivalent of what I get with `foo_ok`, just with the relevant dimensions changed from 30 to 10.

Comment: Basically I need things that work with the form `foo = [(X, Z), (Y, X)]` where it might be the case that `Y==X`. But I don't see why having `Y==X` should cause things to fail.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius In short, you should not have numpy arrays of such type. Numpy is not optimized to deal with `object` arrays. Use raw python lists for that purpose.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius a while ago I wrote a [similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29518186/764322) on why not to use object types with numpy. They don't work as expected, and don't give you any particular benefit from using them instead of raw python lists.

Comment: So NumPy is (too) smart here (or not smart enough): it's "failing" (happily) in the case where the the first dimension of the arrays doesn't match, giving me a list of two arrays (which is what I want); but when they do match it tries to stack them, but then fails (unhappily) when the other dimension doesn't allow it?

Comment: And: I assume I just avoid the whole problem with: `[np.zeros(foo_bad[0]),np.zeros(foo_bad[1])]`; right?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius yes, that is why *smart* was in italics haha. Numpy is built to handle numerical arrays of fixed data-type and contiguous memory in order to use its full potential. If you use arrays of `objects`, I can't think of any benefit from using numpy arrays instead of list. So yes, I would suggest using just raw python lists (with numpy arrays inside).

Comment: Benefit: In my code I multiply the result by a float in a single step (e.g. `k * a`). I can't do that with a list (without iterating, `[k * ax for ax in a]`).

Comment: Actually, its worse than that. I have a lot of lines like `a_new -= k * a` which get messy with lists. Is there any way to force `np.array(...)` to not glom things together when the dimension matches?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius find edited the *dirty* way of creating numpy `object` arrays with same shape in the first axis. I still would think on separating numpy arrays in 2 or something like that, but if it is still what you want, you *can* do it.

Comment: Brilliant — but (*ugh*): now the error appears at lines like `a_new -= k * a` (which must be repeating the problem behind the scenes). I'll have to decide whether to use lists and rewrite all those clever lines using list comprehensions, or just forbid cases where the fist axes of neighboring elements match (which *may* actually be ok in my application).

Comment: That last `np.empty(...dtype=object)` is my preferred method if I have to get around `np.array's` attempts at creating a higher dimensional array.